# Confused on how to read xml object returned by curl in php

Tags: php, xml, curl, xmlhttprequest

This is my php code:

```
<?php   
if (array_key_exists("site", $_GET) && $_GET["site"] != "" )
{ 
    $url = $_REQUEST['site'];
    $url = " http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_query2?target=";   
    $result= $url.urlencode($url); 
    $process = curl_init($result); 
    //init curl connection
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
    $resp = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process); 
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
}
?>
```

Assumed xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <query target="example.com">
   <application name="0" r="89" c="44"/>
   <application name="1" r="89" c="46"/>
   <application name="2" r="92" c="47"/>
   <application name="4" r="93" c="48"/>
 </query>
```

I know how to read this kind of xml file

```
<Status>
    <code>200</code>
    <request>geocode</request>
</Status>
```

`$status = (int) $xml->Status->code;`

The above xml has repeated tags such as `application`, how can I read certain ones?

Comment: Side note: Aren't you writing over the value of `$url`? Shouldn't it be something like `$result= $url.urlencode($_REQUEST['site']);`?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a mistake

Comment: *(sidenote)* libxml based extensions like SimpleXml can be used with custom stream contexts, so there is technically no need to use CURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application` items will be accessible as an array, example: `$xml->application[3]`

```
$x = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <query target="example.com">
   <application name="0" r="89" c="44"/>
   <application name="1" r="89" c="46"/>
   <application name="2" r="92" c="47"/>
   <application name="4" r="93" c="48"/>
 </query>');

 print_r($x); // View entire XML structure

 print_r($x->application[1]); // View the 2nd application item

 echo $x->application[1]['c']; // Get 'c' attribute from 2nd item (46)
```

Comment: Or you can use attribute() function of SimpleXMLElement class, for getting attributes.

Comment: Here im getting an error     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
String could not be parsed as XML.How should i convert $resp into an Xml

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml->application[0];

$xml->application[1];

$xml->application[2];

...
```

Comment: I think the root element isn't accessed as a separate object, so you can retrieve the children of the root directly, like $xml->application[0],$xml->application[1], etc. And $xml['target'] to access the root attributes.

Comment: @user570783, you right for this example . Thank you. I will edit my answer. But if there are two or more <query> , still he have to use this element as an object :)

Comment: But... there can't be more than one root, that wouldn't be well formed xml.

Comment: no , no you misunderstood me because of my bad English :) . As i said, you right.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers you can also use XPath to get certain elements from an XML structure:

`$xml->xpath('/query/application[@name=2]')`

will return the `<application>` element with attribute `name = 2`. See [w3schools XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for more info on conditions. Just keep in mind that XPath is somewhat slow in PHP with SimpleXML, even though you won't notice it unless you have a large document with thousands of elements. It's a good way of seeking not-so-big XMl structures. If you have to deal with large sets you might want to switch to DOMDocument. It isn't as simple and easy to follow but it has much greater performance with XPath.

**Update**

I see you're trying to parse full response as XMl. But $resp will actually contain FULL response, I mean including headers. Of course it won't parse correctly. What you need to do is:

```
//...
$resp = curl_exec($process);
$resp = substr( $resp, curl_getinfo($process, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE) );
curl_close($process); 
//...
```